# gapps install on CM11 failed- or did it?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, google-apps

```
Verizon Droid Razr Maxx
cm-11-20141112-SNAPSHOT-M12-spyder.zip 
gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip
```

I got this error when I flashed the gapps zip:

```
Updating partition details...
E:Unable to mount '/osh'
Installing '/sdcard-ext/gapps/-kk-20140606-signed.zip'....
checking for MD5 file...
Skipping MD5 check: no MD5 file found.
**********************************************
          Google Apps for Android 4.4.3
**********************************************
Installing files...
Cleaning up and setting metadata...
set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed.
E:Error executing updater binary in zip '/sdcard-ext/g....'
Error flashing zip '/sdcard-ext/gapps-kk-20140606-sign....
E:Unable to mount '/osh'
```

After wiping the dalvik cache and rebooting I got an "Android is upgrading" message and I saw google maps and other apps.

Haven't dug into this yet, but I guess it worked? Whats the deal with that error I got? What part of the install failed and caused it to report a status of failed?

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you are root user)

I don't know the error but I think you could extract the APKs from that zip and install them manually.

Then, with a tool like Link2SD you could long press each Google App and select the option "Convert in System app". That's pretyt much the same like flash the apps via recovery and zip (in this case).

Comment: But it looks like they did install and seem to be working ok. I just want to know what the cause of the error was in case there is something wrong I don't see yet.